In Rstudio, how did global options take effect?
In r studio, there is a global option under "Tools" in the menu.
I changed the package default package repo to
https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN

But in the options(), the repos setting is
https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/__linux__/centos7/2024-04-07

I asked chatgpt, it tells me in this case, the options() takes priority.
So I was wondering when I changed setting in global option, what file or what variable is actually changed so that R knows it was changed and it can have the sense of the priority that options is higher than global options.
I checked the project's .Rprofile and my ~/Renviron folder, both not changed when I change global options.

Well, do you set a repository in .Rprofile or Rprofile.site or anywhere else? The URL looks like a CRAN snapshot.

@Roland, I think no. It doesn't matter, I want to know how did global option setting change take effect. It must through some way.

You clearly have made some settings that supersede this global option because R doesn't know about them.

@Roland I didn't manually change it, but I was using renv, may be it has some settings I don't know.

On a standard windows Rstudio setup, changing your CRAN mirror on global options would be recorded into a file :
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\rstudio-prefs.json

Do you know how about linux system?

on my system : ~/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json
